# "Response too large to return" even with --allow_large_results

Tags: limit, google-bigquery, resultset

Sometimes after many successful processing of 1 million rows dataset, I got “Response too large to return” error message. Same message was thrown when I tried 2 million rows datasets. Is there a limit for transaction size?

Error message:
BigQuery error in query operation: Error processing job '...': Response too large to return.

Query submitted:
bq --project_id=... query --destination_table ... --append_table --use_cache --allow_large_results   "select  ...   from ...  limit 1000000"

Comment: add more information showing some code

Answer (score 2):

Queries that have a `LIMIT` clause can cause this error even when `--allow_large_results` is set.  Enforcing the `LIMIT` clause forces all the output data through a single node, which removes the ability to return large results.  Try removing the `limit 1000000` from your query.

We're working on adding this to the limitations in our [documentation for large query results](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#largequeryresults), but it hasn't been added there yet.